# Thumbnails are not created in Drupal 7

Tags: users

When selecting an image to a user profile, the original is saved in files/pictures, however no thumbnail is created. (also other app like Node-Gallery fail to create thumbnails).

Directories where the thumbnails should be stored were not created by default, so I created the missing folders myself (files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures).

Turning off clean URL didn't work (as suggested by someone).

GD libraries are installed.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Marcel

Comment: Marcel, welcome to Drupal Answers. A couple of questions seem identical or at least similar to yours: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/19152/226 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/53537/226. Also, to be able to help you it would be helpful if you describe your current setup (OS, webserver, PHP version). That said, the first thing to check are the ownership and permissions on the files folder, as described in the top 3 answers on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/373/226.